# Programming style in Float operations

Tags: c++, delphi, coding-style

I happen to come across some similar kind of programming styles mostly when there is an **Float or Double operations**.

```
ratio = 1.0 * (top - bottom) / (right - left);
```

All variables involved are float.
What is the significance of having `1.0` multiplied to the result?
As per my thinking multiplying `1.0` is some extra burden.Since the result wont change.

Or is it similar to write an condition having `and  1==1`.

P.S: There are some situations where in some variables(except ratio) are assigned to non Float/double values as a long or integer.

Comment: What language? What platform?

Comment: @Oded Have seen this in C++,Delphi.

Comment: real factor 1.0 causes compiler to treat a part of expression as real (which can be integer otherwise), that's all

Comment: Split your statement into [three-address code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_address_code) to figure out where type conversion might occur. [Aho, Sethi, Ullman] for more details.

Comment: @user539484: It does not depend on three-address-code, but rather on the rules of the language (in particular precedence ordering and automatic type conversions/promotions).

Comment: @phresnel, ugh, i didnt said *that*. Read on 3AC to see how it reveals the point where conversions occur.

Comment: @user539484: I know for sure what this is about. Still it depends on the ruleset of the language where the conversion occurs. Some languages forbid implicit conversions entirely (3AC won't reveal anything), some languages evaluate strictly left to right, some have well defined operator precedence (you need this knowledge to make any sense of 3AC). A language might also say: If the lhs of assignment is float, any operand on the rhs is converted to float before commiting any operation. I am not saying 3AC is completely useless, but you need to know the semantics of the language first.

Comment: @phresnel, sure, its impossible to split an expression to 3AC w/o knowing operator precedence and operator typization. However, OP presented general arithmetic expression where common precedence rules apply. And if autoconversion is forbidden then 3AC will reveal the point of type error.

Comment: @Shirish11, you misconception is here - *1.0 multiplied to the result*. Expression will be evaluated left-to-right, so 1.0 is multiplied to dividend, not to quotient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**C/C++**

When one or more of the variables `top`, `bottom` etc. are of type `double` then the multiplication by `1.0` is pointless. You should simply remove it since it serves no purpose. When all of the variables are of type `float` then the multiplication by the `double` literal `1.0` forces the expression to be evaluated with double precision arithmetic.

On the other hand, when *all* of the variables are integers, the multiplication by `1.0` forces the calculation to be performed with floating point arithmetic. Without the multiplication the calculation would be performed with integer arithmetic which would yield a different result.

My guess is that the code originally used integers and the `1.0` was needed. At some point in time the code was changed to use floating point variables but the now spurious multiplication was not removed.

**Delphi**

If you saw such an expression in Delphi code then you should simply remove the multiplication. The presence of a division operator forces the expression to be evaluated as a floating point expression.

The rules for Delphi expression evaluation are a little different from C and C++. In C and C++ a single symbol, `/` is used for both integer and floating point division, with the context of the expression determined which form of division is used. In Delphi `/` is floating point division and `div` is integer division.

Comment: I think the last part is ambiguous: `division is a separate operator in Delphi, div and the / operator always means floating point division`. I propose `division is a separate operator in Delphi (namely div), the / operator always means floating point division`

Comment: Yeah, that's better than my proposal :)

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the rule of thumb is

> *If the operation involves a floating type, both operands are converted to the floating type (the result is of floating type)*

Keep in mind that `operation` is very related to `operator`. And the order of operations is determined by
[operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).

Precedence of the basic operations in C++ is quite natural w.r.t. maths:

- `*`,`/` happen before `+`,`-`
- expressions within `(`, `)` happen first

So if you have

```
float f = 1.0f + 1 / 2;

// then `f` will be `1.0f`, because

int   sub = 1 / 2     ;  // <- an integer division, happens first and gives 0
float f   = 1.0f + sub;  // <- 0 because the division result was evaluated first
```

The final result is of type `float` because the last operations is a `float + int`.

Another example, involving braced expressions:

```
float f = (1.0f + 1) / 4;

// `f` will be `0.5` this time. The braced expressions happens first:

float sub = 1.0f + 1;  // float + int = float
float f   = sub / 4;   // float / int = float
```

Here it is important to note that the conversion of `4` to `4.0f` happens **before** the operation, like in this exemplary assembly:

```
// [mnemomic] [what]+ [target]
fload 1.0f, float_register_0
fload 1,    float_register_1
fadd  float_register_0, float_register_1, float_register_2 // sub is in [2]
fload 4,    float_register_3                               // 4 is in [3]
fdiv  float_register_2, float_register_3, f                // [2]/[3] -> f
```

---

***Remember***

> *If the operation involves a floating type, both operands are converted to the floating type (the result is of floating type)*

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `1.0` is a `double`, so it would increase the precision of the calculations. It would be clearer to just explicitly cast to `double` if that's the intention though. It's also not in an ideal place in the expression if this is the intention (`top-bottom` will be evaluated before the increase in precision).

There could hypothetically be additional reasons for it though, like the constant used to be `2.0` but over time was fine-tuned to `1.0`, hiding the original reason for this multiplication. Judging from the calculation you're performing, I don't think this was the case.